# Blackberry over the air installation

Tags: blackberry, installation, jad, ota

I uploaded my blackberry application's delivarables to a server. I want my users to install the application from an url. Before uploading to remote server i made tests on localhost. No problem. But when i try to download .jad file from server it displays the file content, doesn't intall the application.

Displayed text:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
RIM-COD-Module-Name: .....
```

I thought it was about mime types so added these lines to .htaccess file in the folder with application files:

```
Options -Indexes
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor .jad
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod .cod
AddType application/java-archive .jar
```

That didn't solve either. I don't know what else to do.

.cod, .jad, .jar .. files all uploaded.

UPDATE: Solved using php.

```
$url = 'http://myserver.com/myapp.jad'
$jadContents = "";
try {
      $file = fopen($url, 'r');
      $jadContents = fread($file, filesize($url));
      fclose($file);
} catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        $jadContents = "";
}
if ($jadContents != "") {
   header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK", true);
   header("Content-Type: text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor", true);
   header("Content-Length: " . strlen($jadContents), true);
   echo($jadContents);
}
```

Comment: The mime types should do it.  Have you confirmed that your web server is really sending the expected mime type in the http headers when retrieving the .jad file?

Comment: Is there a way to confirm it from the browser?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, unfortunately.  You could throw together a simple app that requests the HTTP link, then debug and check the headers on the HTTP connection while it is open...

Comment: Or, if the URL is public, try this: http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php

Comment: You were right. Returned type is text/plain. Thanks for helping. I guess the problem is with apache server but what should i do now? I have no idea.

Comment: Hello Mucie, I am also trying the same task. to use OTA in my app. please can you guide the process.?:(

Comment: Hi @samintechvalens. I solved the issue with using php. I shared the code in the question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable [.htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html), you need to add

```
<Directory /somedir>
Allowoverride All
</Directory>
```

to httpd.conf